# Wordpress always redirects to https after copying to localhost

Tags: wordpress, http, https, mamp

When I copy my wordpress installation from server to a local webserver (MAMP) and try to access `localhost:8888`, it always redirects http to https. So I always get an `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.
I can't find the setting for this anywhere – neither in the database nor somewhere else in the wordpress files. Can anybody help?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory see this link may be useful of you....

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?  I hate questions that are abandoned

Answer (score 14):

Make sure that `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` are set to addresses that start with `http`, not `https`.

These settings should be located in `wp-config.php`.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost:8888');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost:8888');
```

Make sure you aren't telling WordPress to force SSL for admin and login.

```
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN',false);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN',false);
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried all the above suggestions and nothing worked. In my case some plugin was probably causing this. It started working after disabling the plugin directory by renaming it to 0_Plugins.

Now I have to manually figure out which of the plugins was causing this.

Thanks for the other tips.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution! I've had to disable better-wp-security plugin. I did this by renaming the folder to 0_better-wp-security.

Comment: thanks a lot ! My case is similar, after renaming the folder for wordfence, the redirect stopped

Answer (score 0):

You need to change .htaccess file in the root of project.
Change it to this code if you want to force Http :

```
# BEGIN Force HTTP
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# END Force HTTP
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, that doesn't work. Maybe it's related to the fact that I have installed the _Really Simple SSL_ Plugin?

Comment: Yes try to disable unistall or move plugin folder and check if it works. Do this for each plugin related to ssl and https

Comment: @TimKohlen yes you are right recently i have gone through same issue.
Really Simple SSL plugin or anyother related to SSL will do the same and https issue will raise.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in wp-config file

define('FORCE_SSL', false);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);

Answer (score 0):

In addition to some of the other answers here, one thing to check that isn't mentioned is is the `use_ssl` meta value in the `usermeta` table.

Regardless of anything else, if it's set to `1`, then it will redirect to SSL.

This applies only if you're already signed in, so could explain a discrepancy between main browser window and incognito/private.

Check the [auth_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/auth_redirect/) function for other causes of redirect.