# Disable SSL on localhost using MAMP

Tags: ssl, mamp

Month ago I've installed MAMP (not PRO) and I set SSL for localhost following this tutorial. It works perfectly by the way:

https://torbjornzetterlund.com/how-to-get-ssl-working-on-mamp-for-os-x/

Today I removed MAMP and install it again, but I can't access localhost with http://localhost, it redirects to https:// and connection is not allowed.

The apache config is the default config.

How can I remove/disable the openSSL I set?

Answer (score 1):

I tried solutions mentioned here without success

[Wordpress always redirects to https after copying to localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954680/wordpress-always-redirects-to-https-after-copying-to-localhost)

But the only thing that worked was to change default MAMP ports under MAMP > Preferences
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. I set up a local host SSL environment for the one site as required to develop with the Facebook Api and instagram api.

When I went to update the site to a fresh directory with the newest version in production, it would fail because the SSL is not setup for the new directory yet. Redirecting me to https://www.localhost.

My solution was to backtrack using documentation on how to enable SSL on the site. What I found is this:

This is tested on MAMP Free version, possibly works on PRO but untested.

The instructions state:

Open /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf and uncomment Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-ssl.conf.

So I navigated to that directory, opened the httpd-ssl.conf file in my text editor and located the uncommented line, commented this line using "#" and save.  Doing this resulted in disabling the ssl behavior and retains all my previous configuration.

When your ready to go back to SSL, uncomment that line and make sure you have reconfigured your ssl to the new directory(Github below explains how to configure for ssl). Here is the github I reference for the work. Good luck!

https://gist.github.com/jfloff/5138826

Line #3

Answer (score 0):

I am using MAMP Free version and *accidentally* launched the PRO version.
It changed ports for the Free version too... So suddenly localhost and other virtual hosts changed to SSL.

Reseting ports in the Free Version with the button "**Set Web & MySQL ports to 80 & 3306**" worked for me.